# How to group shapes in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store

Help me, please. I have this:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Name="MyObject" Fill="Red" ManipulationDelta="Object_ManipulationDelta" Height="80" Width="80" ManipulationMode="All">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="1">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

And I have function `Object_ManipulationDelta` which change position of element if it is dragged.

1. So, how I can group all Rectangles (or some of them; like array), and use one function `Object_ManipulationDelta` for change location whole group if one of them is dragged? In function I use this: `var obj = (CompositeTransform)MyObject.RenderTransform` and `TranslateX` (and Y) for obj.
2. Is there a way to not write `<Rectangle.RenderTransform...` after each rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just name the whole Grid you have mentioned in your code sample using x:Name="name" and apply the transformation on this Grid. Or group only the target rectangles in nested Grid and apply the transformation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Any Panel such as Grid can do the grouping job. Grid has ManipulationDelta event too. 
To avoid duplicate Composite transform move it to a grid containing the rectangles.